# Is it possible to disable PrincipalPermission check for WCF-services in web.config

Tags: wcf, principalpermission

My wcf-services uses Principalpermissions for authenticating users like follows:

```
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="WCFUser")>
```

Is there any possibility without changing source code to disable this PrincipalPermission check, like a section in web.config or something similar

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/4250824.aspx) for the problems that you mentions in your post